# I want to use Firebase Authentication on Actions on Google

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am a beginner of Actions on Google.
I am creating an application on Actions on Google.

I would like to use Firebase Authentication.
In that case, should I use the AccountLinking function?

Can you tell me specific instructions?

It will be appreciated if you can also provide sample code of index.js.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: You'll have the best luck getting an answer if you provide the code you've tried so far. That gives everyone a reference to how well you understand what you're trying to do, and to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I referred to the following URL.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

The code of index.js is as follows.

```
var App = require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp;
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var firebase = require('firebase');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request that can provide a "message" field in the body.
 *
 * @param {!Object} req Cloud Function request context.
 * @param {!Object} res Cloud Function response context.
 */
exports.testMethod = (req, res) => {
    // Initialize Firebase
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential:admin.credential.cert({
            apiKey:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            authDomain:"test.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL:"https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com",
            projectId:"test",
            storageBucket:"test.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId:"xxxxxxxxxxx"
        })
    });

    var app = new App({request:req, response:res});
    let user = app.getUser();
    console.log('User is ' + user);
    let id_token = app.getUser().accessToken;
    console.log('accessToken is ' + accessToken);

    //var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token

    // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
    var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);

    // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        var email = error.email;
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        var credential = error.credential;
        // ...
    });
};
```

The following error has occurred.

```
Error: Certificate object must contain a string "private_key" property. at FirebaseAppError.Error (native) at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:25:28) at new FirebaseAppError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:70:23) at new Certificate (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:108:19) at new CertCredential (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:174:33) at Object.cert (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:175:58) at exports.testMethod (/user_code/index.js:15:34) at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:684:7 at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:668:9 at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
```